# Stopwatch ElapsedMilliseconds gives 0 in few cases during the performance load test

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

we get the "0" milliseconds logged in few cases during the load test but not able to create this issue during the dev test. Anyone has 
experience the same issue and willing to know if any best practice around 
    using the Stopwatch.

```
private Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
[HttpGet]
[Route("/Test")]
public string TestStopWatch(bool throwExcetion)
{
    stopWatch.Start();

    try
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2 * 1000);
        if (throwExcetion == true) throw new Exception("exception thrown");
        return "Method executed successfully";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "Method is thrown exception";
    }
    finally
    {
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($" Elapsed Time: {stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString()}");
        stopWatch.Reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `Thread.Sleep` ? - if you simply want a logical delay, make your method `async` and then use `await Task.Delay(2000)`. Unless of course you are trying to stop/block the current thread

Comment: What do you mean by "load test" and "dev test"?

Comment: Try to move the new StopWatch INSIDE the function

Comment: @Max: I'm curious.  What difference would that make?

Comment: maybe the value of the stopWatch is shared if you run test in parallel. Maybe the Zero read is referred by another method (not listed in the code) that use the same variable

Comment: To elaborate on @Max's answer, don't just put `stopWatch = new Stopwatch()` into the method, but actually move the whole declaration (`Stopwatch stopWatch = new new Stopwatch()`) into the method. You want a per-call instance, not a per-controller instance.